# Why is this code printing None?

Tags: python

Tried to execute the below program along with values its printing `None`. Can anyone help me why its printing `None`?

```
class Myself(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.record={}
    def __iter__(self):
        self._roles = list(self.record.keys())
        #print ("in iter self._roles",type(self._roles))
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self._roles:
            return self._roles.pop()
        else:
            StopIteration

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.record[key]=value
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.record.get(key,"No record found")

    def list_all(self):
        for detail in self.record:
            print (self.record[detail])

def main():
    mydetails = Myself()

    mydetails['name']='Python'
    mydetails['age']='26'
    mydetails['job']='software'
    mydetails.list_all()

    for x in mydetails:
        print (x,":",mydetails[x])

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should raise `StopIteration`:

```
def __next__(self):
    if self._roles:
        return self._roles.pop()
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *raise* the `StopIteration` execption:

```
def __next__(self):
    if self._roles:
        return self._roles.pop()
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Because you don't `raise` it, you are merely referencing the name, which does nothing. Then the `__next__` method just ends, resulting in a default implicit `return None`.